# Is there a way to Recursively restructure and Expand a dictionary in a parent child format in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
    {"Basketball": 
        {"Athlete": 
            {"LeBron": "SF"}
        }
    }
```

My expected output is:

```
    {
        "value": "Basketball",
        "label": "Basketball",
        "children": [{
            "value": "Athlete",
            "label": "Athlete",
            "children": [{
                "value": "LeBron",
                "label": "LeBron",
                "children": [{
                    "value": "SF",
                    "label": "SF"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

My actual output is an index out of range error

What I have done so far is:

```
    loaded_json = json.loads(basketballjson.content)
            data_queue = [(k,v) for k, v in loaded_json.items()]
            root = "Basketball"
            p_graph = {"value": root, "label": root, "children": []}
            for tuple in data_queue:
                level = tuple[2]
                g = p_graph["children"]
                for i in range(level - 1):
                    for e in g:
                        if tuple[1] == e["value"]:
                            g = e["children"]
                flag = 0
                for e in g:
                    if tuple[0] == e["value"]:
                        flag = 1
                        break
                if flag == 0:
                    g.append({"value": tuple[0], "label": tuple[0], "children": []})
                return g
```

With the flatten_json module I've only been able to transform the data as such:

```
loaded_json = json.loads(basketballjson.content)
flatten_json.flatten_json(loaded_json)
Output: "Basketball_Athlete_LeBron": "SF"
```

Here is my attempt at recursion:

```
     def expand_result(data, output_array=None):
        if output_array is None:
            output_array = []
        for parent, child in data.items():
            if isinstance(child, dict):
                output_array.append({"value": parent,
                                     "label": parent,
                                     "children": [{
                                         "value": child,
                                     }]})
        return output_array
```

I have been trying to unpack this dictionary for a while but seem to only run into how to flatten dictionaries, not expand/organize them visually. I have been trouble trying to traverse this tree. Any help is greatly appreciated. I would also like to k

now how to expand any dictionary of any size this way as well.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this transformation? Also, did you try solving the problem via recursion?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes I have I've only been able to flatten the data though using flatten_json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a recursive function has to call itself. It is not the case in your attempt so it cannot work.

Let's define a true recursive function :

```
def recurs(inp):
    if isinstance(inp, dict):
        outp=[]
        for parent, children in inp.items():
            outp.append({"value":parent,'label':parent,"children":recurs(children)})
        return outp
    else:
        return {"value":inp,'label':inp}
```

So now apply it to your data :

```
import json

sports="""    
{"Basketball": 
        {"Athlete": 
            {"LeBron": "SF"}
        }
    }"""

data=json.loads(sports)
print(recurs(data))
```

This gives :

```
[{'value': 'Basketball', 'label': 'Basketball', 'children': [{'value': 'Athlete', 'label': 'Athlete', 'children': [{'value': 'LeBron', 'label': 'LeBron', 'children': {'value': 'SF', 'label': 'SF'}}]}]}]
```

It looks like the wanted result. Now the question is what would you do whith a such weird structure ? But it's not my matter.

Comment: Sorry, I did a bad copy-paste resulting in a wrong solution posted. This should be now fixed. I've edited the solution.